# How can I discover which packages were installed or updated in a specific ubuntu-release-upgrader?

Tags: package-management, upgrade, dpkg

In my `/var/log/dpkg.*` file, I have the entries `upgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:all 1:20.04.33 1:20.04.35` and `ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:all 1:20.04.33 1:20.04.35`

I assume this means these packages were upgraded from 20.04.33 to 20.04.35.

Is there an authoritative source which details which specific packages were installed / upgraded as part of this release?

Comment: Those *are* specific packages: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ubuntu-release-upgrader-core They were upgraded from `1:20.04.33` to `1:20.04.35`.